# User input line by line by hit enter

Tags: bash, shell

I want to make a script , when user inputs endless new lines (with enter) and when he hits dot (.) then enter it will stdout his list to file.
just like "mailx -s" command.

for example:

```
Enter names (hit dot (".") to interrupt) :
name1
name2
name3
name4
and so on

.
EOF
```

I have try the following:

```
read -rp 'Please enter the details: ' -d $'\04' data
declare -p data
```

The exist code is ctrl+D,
And what i need is dot as an exist code to an file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Replace `$'\04'` with `.`.

Comment: @Cyrus. That's tempting, but would fail on input with a `.` that is not on a line by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll modify William Pursell's answer slightly, since you might as well read into an array rather than overwriting the same string every time (which is O(n^2)):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# or use echo if you want the prompt on a separate line
printf 'Please enter the details: '

lines=()
while IFS= read -r line && [[ "$line" != . ]]; do
  lines+=("${line}")
done

printf '%s\n' "${lines[@]}"
```

See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 if you haven't already, it covers using `IFS=` and `-r`. You *might* not want `IFS=` depending on your exact requriements.

Comment: And be aware of the impact of `-r`.  As a user, I typically *want* to be able to apply escape sequences and I expect them to be honored.  If you read the input with `-r` you prevent normal interactive usage.  Line continuations are an important feature that should not be wantonly discarded.

Comment: While I agree it has its uses, IMO escape sequence parsing should be something people opt-in to when needed, and it's unfortunate that `read` makes it the default behavior. If the default was flipped we'd never even have to discuss this behavior because people who need it would just pass the "parse escape sequences" flag when needed and be done with it :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to read it all with a single read.  Do a loop and check each line.  Something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

content=
while read line && test "$line" != . ; do
        content="${content}${line}
"
done

printf "%s" "$content"
```

Comment: Agreed with reading in a loop, but also use `-r` and (typically) `IFS=` - https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: @dimo414 I totally disagree on the rampant use of `-r`.  More often than not, an escaped newline should not be treated as a raw escape character terminating the input, and blindly applying `-r` is a mistake.  Unsetting IFS is pointless when there is only one variable, and if there are multiple variables being read then unsetting IFS is probably not the desired behavior.  Blindly following that recipe without understanding the impact is a mistake.